# How can I use WindowBuilder core in Eclipse Kepler to make a simple window?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder, eclipse-kepler

I have just downloaded the "**Eclipse IDE for Java Developers**" (version: **Kepler Service Release 1 for Windows 64bit**) and extract it to a folder.

The [Package Description](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr1) says that the IDE includes WindowBuilder Core.

So I created a <kbd>New</kbd> -> <kbd>Java Project</kbd> using the default settings and pressing <kbd>Finish</kbd>. Then I created a new class file with a `public static void main()` inside it.

Then I search all the toolbars but I can't find the WindowBuilder Toolbar anywhere so that to be able to create a new window..

**How can I access the WindowBuilder Core from my Eclipse and show up the toolbar with buttons and textboxes e.t.c.?**

**How can I make and run a simple window with WindowBuilder?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the second part of my question my own, sorry for any inconvenience.

***1) How can I make and run a simple window with WindowBuilder?***

As **lakshman** said,

- Go to **File -> New -> Other**. The **"select a wizard"** window pops up.
- Double click in **WindowBuilder** folder and then to **Swing Designer** subfolder.
- Click to the **Application Window** and then click **Next**.
- Give a **Name** for your new window and then click **Finish**. The **Source** code of the new Window pops up.
- Press **Run** (the "Play" icon of the toolbar) to run your newly created window.

***2) How can I access the WindowBuilder Core from my Eclipse and show up the toolbar with buttons and textboxes e.t.c.?***

To access the **core WindowBuilder** you have to switch to the **Design View** of your newly created window. To do that, just press the **Design** tab at the end of the window tab. You will see the core WindowBuilder Toolbar (or "**Palette**") and you will be able from here to drag-n-drop the controls you want into you window.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

- File--->New
- New----->Other
- Select WindowBuilder
- WindowBuilder----->Swing Designer
- Swing Designer---->Application Windows(Click)
- Application Windows---->Next
- And Now Give the name and your WindowBuilder is ready

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the class -> Open With -> WindowBuilder Editor

Comment: Worked for my case. I didn't had to create new file but to edit already existed file build with WindowBuilder which I had imported along with the project.

Answer (score 1):

Use **File**-->**New**-->**Other** to open the "select a wizard" window. Then type `window` in the search field at the top, which will show Window Builder wizards. Then select **Application Window**.

Give a name in name text field. Then you have created a simple project. Right click the Java file from Project Explorer and select **Run as...** --> **Java Application** to run the generated app.

Comment: That is correct @lakshman BUT where is the toolbar with buttons and textboxes e.t.c. to drag-n-drop whatever i want? Where is the design view?

Comment: The WindowBuilder toolbar is only active when you have opened a UI class in the Window Builder editor. Have you opened the generated application window class?

Comment: @E-Riz I have described in my initial post what steps i have done exactly. How can i open a UI class? Where is the WindowBuilder editor, how can i access it?

Comment: If you don't know how to open a class in Eclipse then you have to start at the beginning to learn to use the tool - way beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow Q/A.
Use **Help** > **Help Contents** and look for WindowBuilder in the table of contents. Read the docs about using WindowBuilder. Also see the Getting Started section under "Java development user guide."

Comment: @E-Riz i looked in **Help > Help Contents** you said but there are instructions only for using the **WindowBuilder Pro**, not for the **core** bundled version that I want... I know the Java language pretty well but I'm new to gui design.

Comment: There's no difference, really. WindowBuilder Pro was the product's name when it was a commercial product before Google bought it and donated the code to Eclipse. The "core" that you speak of is just one of the Features that makes up the WindowBuilder "product." The Help documentation should apply equally well to what you have.

Comment: BTW, Features are an Eclipse concept that represent an installable unit, usually multiple plugins that go together.